# how to modify this particular query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

```
SELECT * FROM foobar
  WHERE userid != '100' AND col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
     OR userid != '100' AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
     OR userid != '100' AND col3 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
```

This query is working fine for me. It will filter basically on two criteria

1. where col1 or col2 or col3 have "test" and
2. userid is not 100.

I have another `col4` which I want that, other than the `above two condition`, it must filter out those results where `col4 = 'y'`

How should I modify this above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your query, You need to change the second `col2` to `col3`. It's easier to see the error if you reformat your code:

```
SELECT * FROM foobar
WHERE (userid != '100' AND col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]') OR
      (userid != '100' AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]') OR
      (userid != '100' AND col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]')
```

I've also added parentheses to make the evaluation order clear. You can rewrite your query to avoid repeating the expression `userid != '100'`. Then just add your missing clause:

```
SELECT * FROM foobar
WHERE userid != '100'
AND col4 <> 'y'
AND (
    col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR
    col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR
    col3 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? You could also separate out the `userid != '100'` since it is common to the three checks.

```
SELECT * 
FROM foobar 
WHERE userid != '100' 
  AND (col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' 
       OR col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' 
       OR col3 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' ) 
  AND col4 != 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM foobar 
    WHERE userid != '100' 
        AND (col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' 
          OR col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
          OR col3 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]')
        AND col4 <> 'y'
```

Comment: If he wants to filter out results with col4 = 'y', shouldn't that last check be reversed?

Comment: @Brandon: Jinx. I think we both caught that at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM foobar 
 WHERE  col4 = 'y'
   OR   (
                userid != '100' 
                 AND (
                                col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' 
                                OR
                                col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' 
                                OR 
                                col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
                            )
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE 
(userid != '100') AND 
(col1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR userid != '100' OR col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]')
AND col4 <> 'y'
```